# How can constants be defined once and reused through all files?

Tags: php

I'm trying to set up a site that has many reusable headers/footers, style information, etc. Is there anyway to define a global constant/function that can be reused from any file without having to try to navigate directories each time?

Something like

```
<html>
<?
    includeAll(); // Would include the necessary files, no matter what directory runs the script
    header(); // Would print the reused <head> information
?>
<body>
...
    <? footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not have access to the php.ini or any other server configuration options.

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path/to/script");
```

Does not work either as the $_SERVER super global returns a locked directory on the server, not the root site directory.

Do I have any options?

Comment: Why do you want to `navigate directories each time`? You can create a file `glob.php` which declares all global functions and constants. Then you only have to include this file by `require_once()`.

Comment: If ```$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']``` always returns the same directory, you can navigate to the directory containing the files and include them. ```require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../www/includes/file.php';```.

Answer (score 1):

In your header, declare a variable with the root information. Your path to include the header will have to be correct, but from there on out you can use `include(MY_ROOT . 'filename.php');`

Answer (score 0):

what's the problem?

```
define('ROOT_DIR', '/var/www/my_page/');
function includeAll() {
    include_once(ROOT_DIR . 'file1.php');
    include_once(ROOT_DIR . 'file2.php');
    include_once(ROOT_DIR . 'file3.php');
    include_once(ROOT_DIR . 'file4.php');
}
```

Comment: He means global as in between files, not scripts.

Comment: Did you alter your answer? Seem not, I think I commented on wrong answer. :/ haha, sorry

Comment: @Nideo yes i did, sorry i misundertand the question at first place

Answer (score 0):

I have been using:

```
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] );
include_once('glob.php');
```

Which sets my include path right at the root of my site.
Not sure if it will work for you though, or if there is a better way?